# How to get a ground truth yaw angle or odometry from Gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, ekf, yaw, ekf-localization-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to do georeferencing with point clouds on Gazebo so I use navsat_transform_node to convert gps to odom information as odometry/gps and I use ekf localization with "odometry/gps" and "imu/data" nodes as I am inspired by [https://answers.ros.org/question/200071/how-to-fuse-imu-gps-using-robot_localization/] but the yaw angle that I take from "odometry/filtered" node drifts even though I set all the drift and noise values to zero in husky.gazebo.xacro file.

Can you tell me what should I do to get a perfect yaw angle on Gazebo or what am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277967/how-to-get-a-ground-truth-yaw-angle-or-odometry-from-gazebo?/) by [Abdulbaki](https://answers.ros.org/users/31967/abdulbaki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-12-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found that when I add the following to the robot urdf file, I get ground truth odometry from "/ground_truth/state" topic.

> ```
> <gazebo><plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_p3d.so" name="quadrotor_groundtruth_sim">
> ```

```
  <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
  <bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
  <topicName>ground_truth/state</topicName>
  <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
  <frameName>world</frameName>
</plugin></gazebo>
```

---

Originally posted by [Abdulbaki](https://answers.ros.org/users/31967/abdulbaki/) with karma: 26 on 2018-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1